# Godot instantiated node doesn't exist in scene tree

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

So i have this script attached to the node "Main" I'm trying to create an instance of element.tscn in the create_element function. When I print "get_parent" it correctly identifies that it's parent is the 'main' node, but it isn't showing up in the inspector as such. To see if it somehow ended up somewhere else i tried printing the node's path but I get an error telling me that the node isn't in the scene tree. My understanding is that it should show up in the tree when I call "self.add_child" (i've also tried it without the word self) but it isn't.

I've attached an image of my scene tree. I'm able to instantiate elements in the inspector, but adding them via script doesn't work.

```
extends Node2D

var combinations = ["Water Fire"]
var results = ["Steam"]
var all_elements = [
    Element_Class.new("Test", "TestType", Sprite2D.new())
]


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass

func check_combination(firstElement, secondElement):
    
    print(firstElement + secondElement)
    if combinations.has(firstElement + " " + secondElement):
        create_element(results[combinations.bsearch(firstElement + " " + secondElement)])
    elif combinations.has(secondElement + " " + firstElement):
        create_element(results[combinations.bsearch(secondElement + " " + firstElement)])
    else:
        print("invalid combination")
        
pass

func create_element(element):
    var new_element = preload("res://Scenes/element.tscn").instantiate()
    self.add_child(new_element)
    new_element.visible = true
    print(new_element.get_parent()) #prints: Main:<Node2D#30752638197>
    print(new_element.get_path()) #throws error: elementhandler.gd:36 @ create_element(): Cannot get path of node as it is not in a scene tree.
    new_element.name = all_elements[all_elements.bsearch(element)].element_name
pass
```

[image of my scene tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gmqb.png)

Answer (score 1):

*The short answer is that I do not know for sure. I'm telling you how I reason about this, how to confirm it, and what you might try to work around it.*

---

Since you didn't have any errors on this part

```
var new_element = preload("res://Scenes/element.tscn").instantiate()
self.add_child(new_element)
new_element.visible = true
```

We can be confident that the problem is not instantiation. The instance was created correctly.

Plus this confirms that `add_child` worked as expected:

```
print(new_element.get_parent()) #prints: Main:<Node2D#30752638197>
```

Now, the error:

```
print(new_element.get_path()) #throws error: elementhandler.gd:36 @ create_element(): Cannot get path of node as it is not in a scene tree.
```

I must conclude that `new_element` is a child of the node where this script is executing, but the node where this script is executing is not in the scene tree.

Is it? Try:

```
print(is_inside_tree())
```

And see what you get.

---

How could it not be in the scene tree? I do not know.

I see `create_element` is called from `check_combination`, but it is unclear to me when in the life time of the node this function will run. What comes to mind is that it might be result of a setter running during initialization.

A pattern I use for those cases is like this:

```
var property:
    set(mod_value):
        if property == mod_value:
             return

        property = mod_value
        if is_node_ready():
             # we call _update_property if the node is ready
             # if the node is not ready, _ready will call it when it is
             _update_property()


func _ready() -> void:
    _update_property()


func _exit_tree() -> void:
    request_ready() # making sure _ready will run again if the Node returns to the scene tree


func _update_property() -> void:
    # code that needs to run when the node is ready
    pass
```

Yes, I wish this was easier.

To be fair, I'm writing Nodes that support being removed from the scene tree, modifying their properties and then added again to the scene tree. Which is not necessary for most of the nodes in a game. *Yet, handling that is only a small part of this pattern.*

---

Since `check_combination` does not return, perhaps we can defer it until the Node is in the scene tree. The quick and dirty way would be like this:

```
func check_combination(firstElement, secondElement):
    await enter_tree
    # …
```

Now, there might be a chance this is not running before entering the scene tree, but after leaving it. For example if the Node is being destroyed, in which case this would never return from await, which I believe is acceptable.

*If Godot tried to resume an await on a freed node, you'd have a runtime error.*

A less quick and less dirty way would be something like this:

```
func check_combination(firstElement, secondElement):
    if not is_inside_tree():
        tree_entered.connect(
            check_combination.bind(firstElement, secondElement),
            CONNECT_ONE_SHOT
        )
        return

    # …
```

The connection done with `CONNECT_ONE_SHOT` will disconnect itself once it is emitted. And all signals will be disconnected when the node is freed, so there won't be any lingering anything.

What could be simpler and perhaps good enough is to always `call_deferred` on `check_combination`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having separate variables for the packed scene and the instance?

```
var scene = preload("res://Scenes/element.tscn")
var new_element = scene.instantiate()
add_child(new_element)
```

Comment: I just tried switching my code to have separate variables and it seems to still have the same results as before.

Comment: I'm guessing now that your path to the element is wrong. 

I see that you're passing `element` as a parameter to `create_element()`. Is this supposed to be part of the path? 

For example `create_element("fire")` should then result in `var new_element = preload("res://Scenes/fire.tscn").instantiate()`? 

If so, you just have to change your path to something like `"res://Scenes/" + element + ".tscn"`. Don't remember string concatenation off the top of my head but should be an easy Google search.